# Are [vsftp] and [vsftpd] dupes?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I came across the tags [vsftp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vsftp) and [vsftpd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vsftpd). Both have similar descriptions and are not related to each other. I would propose to alias vsftp to vsftpd (or the other way around). Because I see not reason for having two different tags here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I'll nuke [vsftp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vsftp) because that's not its name.